Proving that $f$ is continuous on a closed interval, then $f$ is bounded (without using the Axiom of Choice)
The below result comes from Analysis 1 by Terence Tao.

Let $a < b$ be real numbers, and let $f : [a,b] \to \mathbf{R}$ be a function continuous on $[a,b]$. Then $f$ is a bounded function.

The usual proof of this result is a proof by contradiction, which starts like this:

Suppose that $f$ is not bounded. Then for any $M \in \mathbf{R}$, there is an $x \in [a,b]$ such that $\left | f(x) \right | \geq M$. In particular, for every $n \in \mathbf{N}$, the set
$$
\{x \in [a,b] : \left | f(x) \right | \geq n \}
$$
is nonempty.
Then we proceed (in the background) to use the Axiom of (countable) Choice to choose a sequence $(x_n)_{n=0}^\infty$ in $[a,b]$ such that $\left | f(x_n) \right | \geq n$ for all $n$.

and then the proof continues as usual.
However, Tao left a footnote explaining that we actually don't need to use the axiom of choice to show that $\left | f(x_n) \right | \geq n$ for all $n$; we can instead define
$$
x_n := \sup \{ x \in [a,b] : \left | f(x) \right | \geq n \} \tag{1}
$$
and then use the continuity of $f$ to show that $\left | f(x_n) \right | \geq n$ for all $n$. This is what I attempt below:

Since $f$ is continuous on $[a, b]$ and since $\{ x \in [a,b] : \left | f(x) \right | \geq n \} \subseteq [a,b]$, then
$$
f \text{ must be continuous on } \{ x \in [a,b] : \left | f(x) \right | \geq n \} \tag{2}
$$
By $(1)$ and the fact that $[a, b]$ is closed, it's clear that $x_n \in [a, b]$ for all $n \in \mathbf{N}$, and because $f$ is continuous on all of $[a,b]$, we must have that it's continuous at $x_n$. This means that on $[a,b], f$ converges to $f(x_n)$ at $x_n$. But by $(1)$, $x_n$ is an adherent point of $\{ x \in [a,b] : \left | f(x) \right | \geq n \} \subseteq [a,b]$, implying that on $\{ x \in [a,b] : \left | f(x) \right | \geq n \}, f$ converges to $f(x_n)$ at $x_n$ .
What this means is that for all $\varepsilon > 0$, there is a $\delta > 0$ such that for all $x' \in \{ x \in [a,b] : \left | f(x) \right | \geq n \}$ satisfying $\left| x' - x_n \right| < \delta$, we have $\left| f(x') - f(x_n) \right| \leq \varepsilon$. Then for any $n \in \mathbf{N}$, we have
\begin{align}
n \leq \left | f(x') \right | = \left| f(x') - f(x_n) + f(x_n) \right| \leq \left| f(x') - f(x_n) \right| + \left | f(x_n) \right | \leq \varepsilon + \left | f(x_n) \right |
\end{align}
That is, we have $\left | f(x_n) \right | + \varepsilon \geq n$ for all $\varepsilon > 0$. This implies $\left | f(x_n) \right | \geq n$, as was to be shown.

Have I showed this correctly? Was this the intended way to show it without the use of the axiom of choice?

You have to know something before this point.  (This result is false for a general ordered field.)  For example, the Heine-Borel theorem...  here ${ x \in [a,b] : \left | f(x) \right | > n }$ is an open cover of $[a,b]$, so what does it mean that there is a finite subcover?

@GEdgar the Heine-Borel theorem for the real line is assumed, yes.
